# Angular Unit Testing - With two beforeEach() methods (one sync and one async), will they always execute/resolve in the correct order?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

my question is basically, are these two code blocks functionally equivalent?

Current set up:

```
    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        imports: [...],
        providers: [...]
      })
        .compileComponents();
    }));
  
    beforeEach(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
```

Alternate set up:

```
    beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        imports: [...],
        providers: [...]
      })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
           fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
           component = fixture.componentInstance;
         });
      }));
```

I have run into some problems in tests where a @ViewChild reference to a MatPaginator in the component will sometimes be `undefined` when running the tests.

I'm wondering if the synchronous function is sometimes executing before the async function completes and the component is fully compiled. Is that possible?

For reference, here is the test that was failing randomly:

```
    it('should correctly generate the true index of status dropdown elements when the paginator exists', () => {
      component.paginator.pageSize = 10;
      component.paginator.pageIndex = 3;
      const trueIndex = component.getTrueIndex(5);
      expect(trueIndex).toBe(35);
    });
// sometimes got Error: cannot set property pageSize of undefined
```

And its definition in the component.ts file:

```
export class MyComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  ...
}
```

Comment: It could be possible. I have ran into scenarios like you mentioned before. What you can do is add a `console.log` in either `beforeEach` and see which one executes first and last.

Comment: I'm confused by all this too, highly convoluted to understand

Comment: Try to add await keyword for the second setup: `await TestBed.configureTestingModule`. IMHO both should have the same outcome.